# How do I copy files from one partition to another

Tags: mount, partition, file-copy

I'am running Ubuntu 16.04 in Virtualbox on a Windows 7 host. I have created 3 other partitions from the virtualbox, and when I run `sudo fdisk -l` I get:
[image: a picture of some text]

So I understand that `/dev/sda` is my master partition and `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`, `/dev/sdd` are my slave partitions.

Now my question is: how do I mount these partitions and copy files from the master partition to any of the other partitions.

I am primitive to ubuntu so please help me by being clear in each step.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please post text as text, so that is easier to read.

Comment: sda, sdb, sbc, sdd are diskdrives (not partitions). Or at least a virtualisation of them. The number is the partition number. There is no slave or master. Hard-disks used to be called slave and master, but that was just ID 0 and ID 1 (maybe once there say something special about ID 0).

Comment: Also you may have more partitions (virtual disks) that are useful/convenient. Especially for a beginner. I am an expert, and would find it hard to find a use for so many.

Answer (score 1):

"Master' and 'Slave' are obsolete and misleading terms which were useful back in the days of MFM drives, but which should not be used on modern HDDs and SSDs. Let's rethink slightly:

```
/dev/sda1 Linux 731 MB
/dev/sda2 LVM   38.4 GB

/dev/sdb  5.1 GB you need to create a partition before use  
/dev/sdc 10 GB you need to create a partition before use  
/dev/sdd 11.7 GB you need to create a partition before use
```

In order to copy files to /dev/sdb , /dev/sdc . or /dev/sdd , you need to partition them, using the rules of VirtualBox, to complete the process of making them virtual disks, and then mount them in the virtual instance of Ubuntu 16.04 . Once you've done that, you can use Ubuntu's [cp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/cp.1.html) command to copy, or use its File Manager to drag-and-drop or select-copy-paste.